# How does a Muslim complete his urination?

Tags: practical-islam, taharah, men, muslim-practices, human-body

I heard that Istibra where one coughs or gets up and walks a little or squeezes the head of the penis to ensure all drops of urine have exited the body is an innovation. Instead he should simply wait a moment or two, not rushing, then wash the head with water and get up. Some light on this matter would be appreciated please.

Answer (score 1):

Whichever method makes you most satisfied that urine will not come out after you have finished. The main reason is in order to keep your clothing clean.